# Breeze Entity property name mapping

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint, breeze

I have a server JSON object that looks like this:

```
{
    "Id": 58,
    "ContentTypeId": "0x010800CC86F2447E566746907284C1DE2DE7F5",
    "Title": "Rework and Drop Test",
    "Priority": "(2) Normal",
    "Status": "Waiting on someone else",
    "PercentComplete": 0,
    "AssignedToId": 93,
    "Body": "Some text",
    "StartDate": "2015-03-06T05:00:00Z",
    "DueDate": "2015-03-13T05:00:00Z"
}
```

And I am using Angular-Gantt which expects its objects to have the property `from` where the object above has `StartDate` and then `to` where the object above has `DueDate`. Is there an easy way to map the name of a property on the Breeze entity to the property on JSON object. For example, Kendo UI's model definition has a `fromField` property that I could use to perform this mapping.

```
to: {
   fromField: 'DueDate'
}
```

I tried the following in breeze.js

```
StartDate: {
   type: breeze.DataType.DateTime,
   name: 'from'
}
```

and

```
from: {
   type: breeze.DataType.DateTime,
   name: 'StartDate'
}
```

But neither of those worked. I also tried `nameOnServer` with the same lack of results. I know that I can generate a naming convention object but the idea of hand writing the mapping of these fields on both the client and the server side seems silly to me to have two giant switch statements that do essentially the same thing in reverse and it does not strike me as maintainable. Any suggestions? I hope I am just missing something in the documentation.

I'm using `v.0.2.4` of `breeze.labs.dataservice.abstractrest.js` and `v.0.2.3` of `breeze.labs.dataservice.sharepoint.js`.

**Edit:**
I did just update to the latest builds and I am still seeing the exact same thing.

Using a naming convention object with the `nameOnServer` property on my entity works. But I'd rather not do it this way.

```
function AngularGanttNamingConvention() {
  return new breeze.NamingConvention({
    name: 'angularGanttNamingConvention',
    clientPropertyNameToServer: clientPropertyNameToServer,
    serverPropertyNameToClient: serverPropertyNameToClient
  });
  function clientPropertyNameToServer(propertyName) {
    return fixUpClientProperty(propertyName);
  }
  function fixUpClientProperty(propertyName) {
    var newName;
    switch (propertyName) {
        case "DueDate":
            newName = "to";
            break;
        case "to":
            newName = "DueDate";
            break;

        case "StartDate":
            newName = "from";
            break;
        case "from":
            newName = "StartDate";
            break;                    
        case "Title":
            newName = "name";
            break;
        case "name":
            newName = "Title";
            break;                    
        default:
            newName = propertyName;
    }
    return newName;
  }

  function serverPropertyNameToClient(propertyName) {
    return fixUpClientProperty(propertyName);
  }
}
AngularGanttNamingConvention().setAsDefault();
```